# Standard way to implement data input table's frontend for Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I need to build a website with the following types of data input table.

[image]

I want to use **html**, **css**, **js** and **bootstrap** for the frontend and **Django** for the backend and **SQLite** also as Django's default database system. Now I am confused about what is the standard way to implement this type of input table's frontend. I can generally implement a table and inside the cell(means inside `<td>` tag) I can put another `<input>` tag to take input data and send it in the database from the user). Or I can use an [editable table](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/editable/#!) (Actually I do not know if it is possible to use this type of editable table to send data in the database or not).

Here I need an **add row** button and **delete row** icon also like the picture to add/remove the input row if needed, and I don't know how to implement it also thus it will easily reachable from the backend.

So please suggest to me what is the best way and how I should implement this frontend thus I won't be trouble to implement this website's backend also.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of saving the table cell data to the backend on blur.
For this you might need to post data without submitting the form.
You can create an invisible form and submit the edited cell data of the form on every blur with row and column value to backend. You can trigger the submission of form programmatically and doing a prevent default to avoid page redirect.
On loading of the page you can get the whole data and use the framework to create table.

Comment: But how I can manage to sent data in the particular fields where I don't know how many rows I will get from the user? cause the fields may be selected or limited. or I should create a new field for a model in every time I get a new row?

Comment: You can think of using the same model to save a particular cell